# Dividing a part of numpy array by a constant

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having trouble understanding what happens when I divide a part of a numpy array by a constant. If I run

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
a[:2] = a[:2]/2
print(a)
```

I get

```
[0 1 3]
```

Why doesn't `a` equal `array([0.5, 1.0, 3])`, and how do I get `a` to equal that?

Comment: `a` is `int` dtype.  It can't hold floats.

Comment: you need to initialize: `a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype='float')`

Comment: I see, thank you! How come ```a=a/2``` works without setting the dtype?

Comment: `a/2` makes a new array; it's not inserting values into an existing one.

Comment: The `a[:2]/2` part did produce a float.  It was `a[:2] = ...` part that changed it the existing `dtype` of `a`.  Think of an array having 'boxes' that can only hold certain kinds of numbers (or other things).  numbers have to be changed to "fit".  `a=...` assigns a new object to a variable, "throwing away" any previous assignment.  `a[:2]=` changes values of an existing array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the comments while writing this example.
However, it is written, so here it goes:

By creating the array and passing only `int`s the array is of type `dtype('int64')` (from the first `print`). You can set it explicitly to `float` as shown for the second example, which delivers your expected output.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
a[:2] = a[:2]/2
print(a)

a.dtype


b = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float16)
b[:2] = b[:2]/2
print(b)

b.dtype
```

Comment: I see, thank you! How come ```a=a/2``` works without setting the dtype?

Comment: In gernal, it is called implicit type conversion, python is taking care of that in contrast to the explicit conversion by setting the type. You can read more about it [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/type-conversion-and-casting). In case of `numpy`it is also called up and down casting (here more [here](https://www.dailysmarty.com/posts/numpy-upcasting).